# Configure nginx for different ports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I have set up my nginx configuration on which I am running two websites on same port .My problem is I don't want to specify port number whenever I opening my website .I am running my websites on port 81 .My problem is if I have these two website abc.com:81 and xyz.com:81 .I need to include the port number while opening them which I don't want so can anyone tell me the possible solution ..

Here is my nginx configuration

```
user  abc;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/passenger-5.0.30;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_max_pool_size 50;
    passenger_min_instances 5;
    passenger_max_instances_per_app 0;
    passenger_pool_idle_time 0;
    passenger_max_preloader_idle_time 0;
    passenger_app_env staging;
    passenger_friendly_error_pages on;

    server {
        listen       81 default_server;
        passenger_enabled on;

        server_name  abc.com;
        root         /var/www/project/current/public;

        location / {

        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
           root /var/www/project/current/public;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
           root /var/www/project/current/public;
        }
    }

    server {
    listen 81 ;
    passenger_enabled on;

    root  /var/www/new_project/current/public;
    server_name xyz.com;

    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html)
    {
      rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html last;
      break;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /500.html;
    location = /500.html
    {
      root /var/www/new_project/current/public;
    }
    error_page 404  /404.html;
    location = /404.html
    {
      root /var/www/new_project/current/public;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: i think conceptually what you do is configure a `location` for each server, both within the port 80 `listen` block. i.e. `/server_a` and `/server_b`. Then you'd have those `location` blocks call `proxy_pass` to your other port.

Answer (score 0):

The default port for HTTP is port 80. Thus, if you listen on port 80, you don't need to specify the port number in the URL since clients will default to port 80 if no other port is specified in the URL.

For all other ports, it is necessary to add the port in the URL though since the client has no other way to figure out the port to connect to in any other way.